# Proteger arquivos php contra acesso direto sem bloquear para o sistema

Tags: php, html, apache, segurança

Em termos de roteamento, meu site se divide em duas partes: Primeiro, ele tem uma pasta app dentro do root, onde fica contido todos os arquivos do site em sistema MVC, e, segundo, ao lado do app, um conjunto de pastas e arquivo que servem pra interceptar a URL digita e redicionar pra route dentro do app que vai chamar o controller que vai chamar a view e aquela história toda.

EDIT: O servidor é em Apache!

```
site.com
|
+--- app
|     |
|     +--- public
|     +--- route
|     +--- ctrl
|     +--- model
|     +--- view
|     +--- bla
|     +--- bla
|     +--- bla
|
+--- tag
|     |
|     +---tag1.php
|     +---tag2.php
|     +---tag3.php
|
+--- page
|     |
|     +---page1.php
|     +---page2.php
|     +---page3.php
|
+--- index.php
```

Bom, o que eu quero fazer agora é: Bloquear o acesso direto via html a todos os arquivos do tipo php, que dentro da pasta de app, mas de modo que eles ainda estejam disponíveis caso eles sejam reaquistados via includes e ajaxs.

Sei que essa questão já foi perguntada N vezes por aqui mas o problema é que todas as soluções (sejam elas via .htaccess ou via edição direta no arquivo php) bloqueia o acesso para o sistema também e o site não carrega.

Enfim, como fazer isso da maneira correta?

Comment: Você usa apache?

Comment: Sim! Apache server!

Comment: Qual sistema operacional você usa? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Windows com wampserver

Answer (score 2):

Eu vou ser simples e direto. A solução que eu daria pra isso seria dividir estruturalmente na aplicação o que é público do que não é.

Como?

Criando uma pasta que contenha todos os arquivos que serão acessíveis ao público e apontando o Apache para ler a partir dessa pasta. Os outros arquivos, idependente de não estar acessíveis para o cliente (navegador), estariam acessíveis ao script, servindo perfeitamente as dependências.

Considere o seguinte cenário: Quero que o usuário acesse meu `index.php`, `contact.php` e `about.html`, porém ele não pode acessar nenhum script de conexão com banco de dados ou classes do projeto, que está dentro da pasta `app`.

Eu faria assim (simulando ambiente Linux):

```
projeto/
       public/
             index.php
             contact.php
             about.html
             css/
                default.css
             js/
               default.js
               jQuery.js

      app/
         classes/
                DBConnection.php
                Mail.php
```

Notou a estrutura acima? Você pode simplesmente apontar o VirtualHost do seu Apache direto para a pasta `projeto/public`, assim:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    #importante apontar para public, não para raiz do projeto
    DocumentRoot /var/www/projeto/public
    ServerName meusite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Com isso, quando você acessar o seu site, você limitará o usuário a acessar somente `index.php`, `contact.php` e `about.html`, bem como as pastas `js` e `css`, com seus respectivos conteúdos.

**Observação**: Se você estiver usando SO como Ubuntu, você provavelmente acessará o VirtualHost na pasta `/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable`.

É assim que faço em todas as minhas aplicações.

E você pode, pelo `public/index.php`, fazer um include de um arquivo que está na pasta `app/classes` normalmente. O PHP conseguirá acessar, mas o navegador não.

Por exemplo, usando uma estrutura semelhante a citada anteriormente, vamos acessar pelo `public/index.php` configurações armazenadas em uma pasta `app`.

Assim:

```
app/
   constantes.php
   functions.php
views/
     index.tpl
public/
     index.php
```

No arquivo `app/constantes.php`, eu tenho:

```
 define('ROOT_DIR', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'));
 define('VIEWS_DIR', ROOT_DIR . '/views');
```

No meu `public/index.php`, eu faço

```
 <?php

  include __DIR__ . '/../app/constantes.php';

  exit(ROOT_DIR); // '/var/www/projeto
```

Resumindo: Defini `public` como a raiz da aplicação.

O erro que muitas pessoas cometem é definir a raiz como a pasta do projeto. Porém, dependendo a situação, isso pode ser ruim, e força o programador a ficar criando várias bagunças no `.htaccess`, sem necessidade alguma.

O padrão usado acima é seguido pelo Laravel Framework.

Comment: Por favor, nunca imite o que o `CodeIgniter` faz, que é colocar um if em cada script de classe para verificar se uma constante, definida do `index.php`, existe, para determinar se você acessou o script diretamente. Isso é feio demais.

Comment: Então tudo que for privado coloca na pasta `app`?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus ou em qualquer outra na raiz. O importante é lembrar que, com essa configuração, o apache só conseguirá acessar o que está dentro de `public`, mas o PHP conseguirá fazer o include das coisas de fora.

Comment: Show. No caso de eu ter uma pasta chamada `img`, para não acessarem, coloco um arquivo `index.php` redirecionando para a página inicial ou com uma mensagem `403`. Com essa estrutura citada por você, a pasta `img` entraria na pasta "privada"?

Comment: Boa ideia! Mas tem alguma coisa errada! Eu tenho que colocar o .htaccess no root (meusite.com) com os seguintes comandos: <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /meusite.com/public/
    ServerName meusite.com
</VirtualHost> E colocar tudo o que está fora de app dentro da pasta public?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus proteger imagens é uma outra história, mas eu faria assim: a mesma coisa que fiz anteriormente, deixando a pasta `img` fora da `public`. Se o usuário se autenticar, eu uso um arquivo `img.php` e com o `readfile` eu leio a imagem "privada", respondendo para o usuário o conteúdo da imagem. Vamos conversar no chat sobre isso, que te explico melhor

Comment: @JHenry você está usando qual sistema operacional? Isso não é `.htaccess`, isso é o VirtualHost do site.

Comment: Meu SO é o windows. E eu to usando ele com o WampServer...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters vamos sim, gostei da ideia.

Comment: Eu achei um arquivo chamado "httpd-vhosts.conf" em "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\conf\extra", cujo conteúdo é: "<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>" Eu tenho que apagar isso e escrever o que você postou? Mas se eu fizer isso, meus outros projetos de sites ficão inacessíveis!