# Preciso impedir o acesso direto (em uma segunda página) em php

Tags: php, html, session

A pergunta é meio confusa, mas vou tentar explicar o melhor possível.
Tenho um servidor apache2 rodando em linux (Raspbian Stretch Lite) com o php7.0 e os mods necessários.

No server tem alguns arquivos, vou listá-los da forma mais minimalista possível,

Esse é responsável pelo formulário:

**/index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8, user-scalable=no' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aut.css">
  <title>Autenticação</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
session_start();
$erro = $_SESSION['msg'];
if (empty($erro)) {

}
else {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$erro');</script>";
  $_SESSION['msg'] = '';
}
?>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form action="aut/resposta.php" method="post"class="login-form">
      <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuário"/>
      <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha"/>
      <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse é responsável pela validação do formulário e criação de uma variável de sessão caso o usuário e senha estejam corretos, essa variável vem de um arquivo dentro do servidor. Além de redirecionar o usuário.

**/aut/resposta.php**

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST["senha"] == "112233oi#" and $_POST["user"] == "Spineli") {

    $arquivo = "/prog/php/escalator/cripto/key.txt";
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "r");
    $key = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));
    fclose($fp);

 $_SESSION['aut'] = $key;
 header("Location: ../site.php");

} else {
 $msg = 'Usuário ou senha incorretos!';
 $_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;
 header("Location: /index.php");
 
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

E esse é o site para aonde o usuário é redirecionado

**site.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Controle Remoto</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$login1 = $_SESSION['aut'];
$erro = $_SESSION['msg'];

$arquivo = "/prog/php/escalator/cripto/key.txt";
$fp = fopen($arquivo, "r");
$login2 = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));
fclose($fp);

if ($login1 !== $login2 or empty($login1)) {
 header("Location: index.php");
}
else {
 $_SESSION['aut'] = '';
}

if (empty($erro)) {

}
else {
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$erro');</script>";
 $_SESSION['msg'] = '';
}
?>
<div class="bonito">
  <div class="bembonito">
 <div class="text1"><p>Controle Remoto</p></div>
 <div class="text2"><p>Direção</p></div>
 <a href="move/sobe.php" class="button4">Sobe</a>
 <a href="move/desce.php" class="button4">Desce</a>
 <div class="text2"><p>Bloqueio</p></div>
 <a href="bloq/on.php" class="button4">Ligar</a>
 <a href="bloq/off.php" class="button4">Desligar</a>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

e então dentro de ***/move*** temos 2 arquivos o **sobe.php** **desce.php**, esses arquivos executam scripts para controlar reles, o código deles é bem parecido

```html
<?php
session_start();
$msg = 'Subindo ou Descendo!';
$_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;
shell_exec('/root/script.sh');
?>
```

Um detalhe:

A variável _Session['msg'] é usada para exibir mensagens, seu funcionamento não interfere com o problema.

**O problema:**

Se alguém digitar 192.168.x.x/move/sobe.php ele passa pela segurança sem problema algum.

**Tentativas:**
Já tentei tudo que eu conhecia,

Tentei colocar php no onclick do botão, mas o php é executado antes de carregar o site, então ele executava a ação antes mesmo do usuário clicar no botão.

Também tentei usar um esquema de Session como fiz nas paginas resposta.php e site.php, mas o problema é que essa variável ficará aberta até que o usuário clique em um dos botões, e se ele nao clicar em nenhum, a variavel continua presente, assim, qualquer um pode acessar entrando em 192.168.x.x/move/sobe.php

Não sei o que fazer, estou disposto a fazer mudanças de todos os tipos sem limitações de linguagem e etc, eu apenas não posso mudar os arquivos de lugar, só preciso que funcione no meu servidor.

Desde já agradeço.

edit:

Me sugeriram um outro post para a solução do problema, porém eu não posso mudar os arquivos de lugar.

Comment: Possível duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/331344/99718

Comment: Não, isso não é uma duplicata. Eu pesquisei muito nesse fórum e em muitos outros para não cometer esse erro.

Comment: Melhor seria configurar o ambiente adequadamente para não servir os PHPs diretamente do que fazer esse tipo de coisa em cada arquivo.

Comment: Como eu posso configurar?

Comment: Essa pergunta que me foi indicada serve somente para includes e Ajax, o que me faz crer que vocês nem leram minha pergunta e já marcaram como duplicata. Mais atenção na próxima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tentou algo do tipo:

```
<?php
    /* no topo de 'sobe.php' */
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
        /* 
           Ai é com você qual cabeçalho enviar, alguns preferem 404 mesmo se
                os arquivos existem, para segurança            */
        header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden', TRUE, 403 );

            /* escolhe a página apropriada para redirecionar os usuários */
        die( header( 'location: /error.php' ) );
```

Comment: Dessa forma eu não consigo acessar os scripts. Sempre sou redirecionado